# e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. please make sure you have the required dependency in the classpath : class com.google.firebase.auth.internal.internalAuthProvider , unresolved supertypes
com.google.firebase.internal.internalTokenProvider

Here is the code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebaseuiexample"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score -1):

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

change to these implementations.